# Android AccountManager needs to overwrite AuthToken

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager

Hi I would like to explicitly overwrite the existing AuthToken of the account manager. I tried using this snippet

```
Log.d(TAG, "finishRenewal");
AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(context);
Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
for(Account ac : accounts){
  manager.setAuthToken(ac, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE, authToken);
}
```

But I can't seem to retrieve the AuthToken. It always give the previous AuthToken.

BTW: I am retrieving the token by this call

```
 AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager
    .getAuthTokenByFeatures(accountType, authTokenType, null, act, null, null,
        new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
          @Override
          public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
            Bundle bnd = null;
            try {
              bnd = future.getResult();
              final String authtoken = bnd.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
              final String userName = bnd.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
              Log.d(TAG, "GetTokenForAccount Bundle is " + bnd);
              if (listener != null) {
                listener.onAccountAcquired(userName, authtoken);
              }
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              if (listener != null) {
                listener.onFail();
              }
            }
          }
        }
        , null);
```

Comment: How do you set the auth token initially? How do you retrieve the auth token? Also make sure your code snippet is correct. Android's AccountManager doesn't have a method called `invalidateAuthToken()` that takes no parameters.

Comment: sorry for that I must have pasted the wrong snippet, nway I've edited it to reflect the correct one. I am retrieving the token by this call:  AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager
        .getAuthTokenByFeatures(params);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the value of `authTokenType` in the second code snippet doesn't equal `AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE` from the first snippet.

Your code passes `AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE` as the AuthTokenType when you set the auth token. Make sure you use the correct AuthTokenType, not the account type, when you set the authtoken.

The AuthTokenType is usually not the same as the account type, as they identify different things.

Comment: Thanks, I may have missed that one. I should give AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS as the parameter for the setAuthToken method.